# Java/Android: Socket closed when offloading work to a thread pool

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets, tcp

I'm experiencing a very puzzling error writing a thread-pooled TCP server on Android. Basically, my code is structured as follows:

1. Standard server loop (blocking call to `socket.accept()` in a loop within its own thread), calling a handler upon an incoming connection:

   ```
   socket = mServerSocket.accept();
   myHandler.onIncomingConnection(socket);
   ```
2. The handler offloads all further processing of the incoming connection(s) to a thread pool:

   ```
   public class X {
       private final ExecutorService receiveThreadPool = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

       [...]

       private final ConnectionHandler mHandler = new MyServer.ServerHandler() {
         @Override
         public void onIncomingConnection(final Socket socket) {

                     MLog.vv(TAG, "Socket status: " + (socket.isBound() ? "bound" : "unbound") + ", "
                                  + (socket.isConnected() ? "connected" : "unconnected") + ", "
                                  + (socket.isClosed() ? "closed" : "not closed") + ", "
                                  + (socket.isInputShutdown() ? "input shutdown" : "input not shut down") + ".");

                     // Process result
                     receiveThreadPool.execute(new Runnable() {
                         @Override
                         public void run() {
                             MLog.vv(TAG, "Socket status: " + 
                                           (socket.isBound() ? "bound" : "unbound") + ... ); // same code as above

                             BufferedOutputStream out = null;

                             try {
                                 out = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                                 out.write(HELLO_MESSAGE);
                                 out.flush();

                                 [rest omitted...]

                             } catch (IOException e) {
                                 [...]
                             } finally {
                                 [close resources...]
                             }

        }
   ```

Note, that the socket is defined as *final* in the handler method's signature, making it accessible from within the anonymous inner *Runnable* class. However, the first write `out.write(HELLO_MESSAGE);` to the output stream fails due to a closed socket exception. logcat output:

```
02-16 17:49:26.383  14000-14057/mypackage:remote V/ManagementServer﹕ Incoming connection from /192.168.8.33:47764
02-16 17:49:26.383  14000-14057/mypackage:remote V/ManagementServer﹕ Socket status: bound, connected, not closed, input not shut down.
02-16 17:49:26.393  14000-14077/mypackage:remote V/ManagementServer﹕ Socket status: bound, unconnected, closed, input not shut down.
02-16 17:49:26.398  14000-14077/mypackage:remote E/ManagementServer﹕ Error communicating with client:
    java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
            at java.net.Socket.checkOpenAndCreate(Socket.java:665)
            at java.net.Socket.getInputStream(Socket.java:359)
            at  net.semeion.tusynctest.network.ManagementServer$1$1.run(ManagementServer.java:79)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

As shown in the log output, somehow the socket changes its status from connected to unconnected/closed right after offloading the Runnable into the thread pool. **If I just remove the ThreadPool.execute lines, everything works as expected**. I have also tried to create my own static *Runnable* class within the outer `class X`, passing the socket as a parameter to the Runnable's constructor. However, this triggers the same problem.

Am I missing something here? In theory, this should work like a charm; but somehow it seems, that upon starting the thread and terminating the handler's `incomingConnection` method, something happens to the socket instance.

Further facts:

- It's not the client's fault either - to the client, it looks like the server closed the socket. And as said, commenting out the thread pool on the server side fixes the problem.)
- You may notice the ":remote" in the logcat output - the server thread is created from within a background service that itself runs in a separate process.
- At the moment, I'm employing a SingleThreadExecutor for the pool, just for testing. The type of executor should make no difference IMHO.
- I tried to use the socket's OutputStream directly (unbuffered), which has not made a difference. The log statements show that the socket itself changes its status.
- If I initialise the BufferedOutputstream in the handler right before executing the thread, this yields a strange "bad file number" SocketException at the `out.flush();` line (possibly this is an IPC problem?!):

  ```
  java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
      at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterSendto(IoBridge.java:546)
      at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:515)
      at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:504)
      at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$100(PlainSocketImpl.java:37)
      at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketOutputStream.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:266)
      at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushInternal(BufferedOutputStream.java:185)
      at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:85)
      at net.semeion.tusynctest.network.ManagementServer$1$1.run(ManagementServer.java:88)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
  Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: sendto failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
      at libcore.io.Posix.sendtoBytes(Native Method)
      at libcore.io.Posix.sendto(Posix.java:206)
      at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.sendto(BlockGuardOs.java:278)
      at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:513)
  ```

Thanks for any hints :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the problem now. Embarrassingly, I've overlooked the most obvious source for trouble, the server loop in my Server class:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      while (mReceiving) {

        Socket recSocket = null;

        try {
            recSocket = mServerSocket.accept();

            // Process connection
            mTcpServerHandler.onIncomingConnection(recSocket);

        } catch (IOException e) {
                // ...
        } finally {
            if (recSocket != null) {
                try {
                    recSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // log, ignore...
                }
            }
        }
     }
   }
 }).start();
```

So, in case the handler offloads the processing to a new thread, the method returns immediately, and the `finally` block of the server loop closes the socket (which was intended originally, but doesn't fit the thread pool approach). Too obvious, sorry for bothering :)